# Export Display - Can't open display

Tags: xorg, environment-variables

I'm running xubuntu 11.10. From php, I'm calling a shell that exports the display and then calls wmctrl. Every time I call wmctrl, I see an error "Cannot open display".

I call my shell from php:

```
$output = shell_exec('/var/www/wmctrl.sh');
```

My hostname is steven-Z-CLASS

Here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=steven-Z-CLASS:0.0
echo $DISPLAY
wmctrl -m
```

When I run this, I see the echoed display value in my php page:

```
steven-Z-CLASS:0.0
```

However, wmctl does not run. I see this error in the apache log:

```
Cannot open display.
```

Any ideas why wmctrl can't open the display?

Answer (score 4):

On the `steven-Z-CLASS` system you'll need to run `xhost +OTHERNAME` where "OTHERNAME" is the name of the system that is running the "wmctrl -m" command.

The `xhost` command allows the user to modify the security on the local X11 server to allow "OTHERNAME" to connect and display graphics on it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I'm running everything on the same machine. I found that if I run this command in a shell `sudo xhost +` before I load the php page, everything works!

Answer (score 2):

`DISPLAY=steven-Z-CLASS:0.0` means:

- screen 0 (after the dot)
- on X server 0 (between `:` and dot)
- on host `steven-Z-CLASS`

Try removing `steven-Z-CLASS` if the machine running the PHP command is the same machine as the X server one:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:0.0
echo $DISPLAY
wmctrl -m
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it but no luck. `sudo xhost +` is getting me there though.