# PlayOnLinux | xrdb: Can't open display ""

Tags: wine, display, playonlinux

I've just installed Wine, Winetricks and PlayOnLinux on Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome GUI). I use mRemoteNG to access Ubuntu remotely.

When I execute  `> playonlinux`  I get the error below:

```
xrdb: Can't open display 1
Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?
```

I've seen the post below and I tried:

```
> export DISPLAY=:0
```

But I get the same error:

```
Looking for python... 2.7.18 - wxversion(s): 3.0-gtk3
selected
No protocol specified
xrdb: Resource temporarily unavailable
xrdb: Can't open display ':0'
1
No protocol specified
Unable to access the X Display, is $DISPLAY set properly?
```

Here is the video driver

```
> sudo lshw -C video
```

```
 *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GD 5446
       vendor: Cirrus Logic
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller rom
       configuration: driver=cirrus latency=0
       resources: irq:0 memory:fc000000-fdffffff memory:febd0000-febd0fff memory:c0000-dffff
```

```
> echo $DISPLAY
```

```
:0
```

Any idea why PlayOnLinux doesn't work?

Many thanks

[xrandr can't open display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138997/xrandr-cant-open-display)

[Export Display - Can't open display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77298/export-display-cant-open-display)